# Checking the length of a word then outputting if the length is greater than 7 characters in C#

Tags: c#

I'm getting a little bit annoyed at myself because I know that this isn't one of the hardest things to work out but..

I have a text file and my program is reading from the text file analyzing the results then outputting them and doing some other things, what I am struggling with is I need my program to read the words in the text file check to see if they are larger than 7 characters and if so create a separate text file which stores the results...

I've tried various things such as foreach loops and trying to create and array to store the data from the text file and I keep getting stuck.

Any suggestions or examples of code that people could help me with?

Thank you

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, so we can help you

Comment: At the moment I have outlines of code that I think could be used to solve it:
foreach (char word in readTextFile)
{
     if (word == ' ')
         wordCount++;
}

I thought that I could use this but as I was trying to I ran into a dead end :/

Comment: You can't ask us to code the solution for you. But if you show us your code for this function we can guide you in getting the results you want and help you with errors.

Comment: @user1236314 - Update your question with what you have actually tried to compile and I will remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
string myTextFile = File.ReadAllText("inputFile.txt");
var longWordsFile = File.CreateText("outputFile.txt");

myTextFile.Split(' ')
    .Where(s => s.Length > 7)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(longWordsFile.WriteLine);

longWordsFile.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("text.txt"))
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(' ');
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(word.Length > 7 ? ">7": "<=7");
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that code only output >7 or <=7 rather than the actual words?

Comment: yes, you can change the line according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be split up into many smaller ones:

1. Fetch all lines from the text file.
2. From the retrieved content, split it into individual words.
3. Iterate through each word and check length.
4. Place big words into a separate collection.

---

Something like:

```
List<string> words = FetchAllWords();
List<string> bigWords = new List<string>();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (word.Length > 7)
        bigWords.Add(word);
}

// Do something with bigWords.
SaveBigWords(bigWords);
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say `FetchAllWords()` is where he's having trouble.

Comment: @JonB: The question title says otherwise.

Comment: that's the problem with vague questions like this. It's nearly impossible to tell what he wants. However, it's hard to imagine someone having trouble using the `Length` property on `string`. Reading individual words from a file is a bigger challenge.

Comment: @JonB yeah thats where i think im having trouble, i dont think i actually know how to check each individual word, what ive been doing currently is analyzing the entire text file..

Answer (score 0):

**Retrieve long texts**

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");
string longTexts="";
var words=content.SelectMany(line=>line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
foreach(string word in words)
{
 longTexts=longTexts+",";
}
```

**Write the long text strings to a new text file**

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(longTexts);
file.Close();
```